# TypeError: 'range' object is not callable without apparent reason

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, range, typeerror

I made a code to make the summary of the numbers of a matrix but i get this error TypeError: 'range' object is not callable and i don't know  why
Here is my code:

```
print ('The summary of the positive and negative numbers of a matrix')
A=[[0 for i in range (col)] for j in range (fil)]
fil=int(input('Number of columns'))
col=int(input('Number of rows'))
auxp=0
auxn=0

for i in range (fil):
    for j in range (col):
        A[i][j]=int(input('Numbers of the matrix'))
for i in range (fil)(col):
    for j in range (fil):
        if (A[i][j]>0):
            auxp=aup+A[i][j]
        else:
            if (A[i][j]<0):
                auxn=auxn+A[i][j]
print ('The summary of the positive numbers is ',auxp)
print ('The summary of the negative numbers is ',auxn)

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-83bec8a1085e> in <module>
      9     for j in range (col):
     10         A[i][j]=int(input('Numbers of the matrix'))
---> 11 for i in range (fil)(col):
     12     for j in range (fil):
     13         if (A[i][j]>0):

TypeError: 'range' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should be iterating over the rows and columns of the matrix as your code does in the first for loop, i.e. like this:

```
for i in range(fil):
    for j in range(col):
        if A[i][j] > 0:
            ...
```

Your code incorrect because it is attempting to call the `range` object:

```
>>> range(fil)
range(0, 10)
>>> type(range(fil))
<class 'range'>
>>> range(fil)(col)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'range' object is not callable
```

So the call to `range(fil)` creates a new `range` object, and then Python attempts to call that object as though it were a function, passing `col` to it as an argument.

Perhaps you should read up on functions and function calls to better understand how functions work in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change the line

```
for i in range (fil)(col):
```

to just

```
for i in range (fil):
```

---

The way you had it, it was a function call on the `range` object, and as the error message says, the result of calling `range()` cannot be used as a callable/function.